# ruby gemfile 229 error

Tags: passenger, phusion, openproject

I am having another issue with Phusion Passenger. I updated my gems, I updated Bundle, I reinstalled Phusion and when I go to hit the web address it gives me. Any ideas?

Here is where I am at now..

```
compile error /home/bistro/openproject/Gemfile:229:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end ...
em "openproject-plugins", git: "https://github.com/opf/openp...
^ (SyntaxError) /home/bistro/openproject/Gemfile:229:in evaluate'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:inbuild'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in definition'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:124:inload'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in setup'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:ingem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:inrun_load_path_setup_code'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in running_bundler'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger
/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:inrun_load_path_setup_code'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153
```

Application root

```
/home/bistro/openproject Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
```

production Ruby interpreter command

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

User and groups

```
uid=65534(nobody) gid=65534(nogroup) groups=65534(nogroup)
```

Environment variables

Comment: You have a syntax error on line 229 of your Gemfile. Can you post that line?

Comment: There is 237 lines in my file here is what I have

Comment: # Load Gemfile.local, Gemfile.plugins and plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../{Gemfile.local,Gemfile.plugins,lib/plugins/*/Gemf$
  next unless File.readable?(file)
  instance_eval File.read(file)
end

gem "openproject-plugins", git: "https://github.com/opf/openproject-plugins.git$

gem "openproject-backlogs", git: "https://github.com/finnlabs/openproject-backl$

gem "openproject-meeting", :git => "https://github.com/finnlabs/openproject-mee$

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a syntax error in your `Gemfile.plugins` file.

Also I suspect that you use ruby 1.8, and OpenProject 3.0 (at least the openproject-plugins plugin is a 3.0 plugin) - that doesn't match. Please use ruby 2.0, fetch the current openproject (and plugin) sources and try again.